# Importar classes java para um projeto de forma automática?

Tags: java, eclipse, importação

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de importar, de forma automática, classes java vindas de um dado diretório local para o meu projeto atual. Por exemplo: Digamos que quando eu aperte um botão "Importar" na minha aplicação, todas as classes java que se encontrarem em "c:/minha pasta/minhas_classes" serão importadas para o meu projeto. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Especificando: Eu estou tentando construir um sistema onde iniciantes de programação enviam sua classe java e o sistema avalia esse código. A princípio essa avaliação seria apenas através de simples casos de teste nas classes que são submetidas no sistema. Mas mesmo assim, para execução de um caso de teste, é preciso ter a classe importada para um projeto. Este é o porque de eu estar procurando uma forma de importar automaticamente Tendo uma pasta específica no servidor onde ficariam as classes que os alunos submetem, se existir uma forma de importar todas para um projeto de forma automática, eu conseguiria realizar o caso de teste em todas elas assim que fossem submetidas.

Comment: Importar em tempo de execução?? Não faz sentido algum isso pra mim.

Comment: São perguntas diferentes. Pode parecer sem sentido, mas é exatamente isso que estou precisando para construir meu sistema. Isso dará resultados a um sistema de avaliação de classes que estou construindo para ajudar alunos iniciantes em programação. É um projeto da minha faculdade

Comment: Não está muito claro o que você quer importar e nem como, seria interessante detalhar melhor isso que você falou nos comenta rios no corpo da pergunta, até para que fique mais objetivo o que você precisa.

Comment: Eu pensei que já tinha ficado bem claro. Bom, fiz uma correção detalhando mais. Obrigado pela sugestão

Answer (score 3):

Amigo você pode usar o pacote 
`com.sun.tools.javac` do JDK para compilar um bloco de código em tempo de execução, ou seja seu código em java compilando outro código em java durante a execução.

Um exemplo:

```
int errorCode = com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(new String[] {
        "-classpath", "bin",
        "-d", "/temp/dynacode_classes",
        "dynacode/sample/PostmanImpl.java" });
```

Mas detalhes de como isso funciona, você pode seguir esse link:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071777/design-patterns/add-dynamic-java-code-to-your-application.html

Espero que tenha ajudado.